# Using the 2.8 Keyboard short cuts in Blender 2.79

Tags: shortcut

I'm planning on teaching Blender later this year, and it's likely I'll be using Blender 2.79. However, to avoid future confusion among my students I'd prefer to have the 2.8 UI & keyboard shortcuts.

Is this possible and if so is there a Keyboard & UI set for Blender 2.79?

Comment: I think that it will be confusing for everyone involved. Students will not be able to follow existing "tutorials", and if they try 2.79 in other computers that use the default shortcuts it can easily turn into a frustrating experience.

Comment: My hope was for a simple transition for this year using 2.79 into next year with 2.80. But I do see your point about frustration.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely no.

While most keys can be customized in Blender 2.79 it is theoretically possible to create a keymap that mimics most functionality available in 2.8, however not all features are possible.

Blender 2.8 has been substantially changed under the hood and significant improvements were made to accommodate lots of new features, not only superficially at tool and UI level, but also keyboard shortcut definitions and settings, key press handling, and even at low level like keyboard and input device handling.

New features like being able to detect where a mouse click happened (over an object or empty area), button press vs button hold, hold and drag actions, active tools that allow simultaneous viewport manipulation, gizmos with tweak drag actions, among others make it impossible to fully recreate 2.8 input model in previous versions.

Otherwise most basic settings like left click select can be emulated or fully recreated.

Whether or not this is practical or worth the effort is a whole other matter.